# Container with two indexes (or a compound index)

Tags: c++, stl, indexing

I have a class like this

```
class MyClass 
{
    int Identifier;
    int Context;
    int Data;
}
```

and I plan to store it in a STL container like

```
vector<MyClass> myVector;
```

but I will need to access it either by the extenal Index (using `myVector[index]`); and the combination of  `Identifier` and `Context` which in this case I would perform a search with something like

```
vector<MyClass>::iterator myIt;
for( myIt = myVector.begin(); myIt != myVector.end(); myIt++ )
{
    if( ( myIt->Idenfifier == target_id ) &&
        ( myIt->Context == target_context ) )
        return *myIt; //or do something else...
}
```

Is there a better way to store or index the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boost::Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) has this exact functionality if you can afford the boost dependency (header only). You would use a `random_access` index for the array-like index, and either `hashed_unique`, `hashed_non_unique`, `ordered_unique`, or `ordered_non_unique` (depending on your desired traits) with a functor that compares Identifier and Context together.

Answer (score 1):

We need to know your usage. *Why* do you need to be able to get them by index, and how often do you need to search the container for a specific element.

If you store it in an [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/), your search time with be O(ln n), but you cannot reference them by index.

If you use an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/), you can index them, but you have to use [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) to get a specific element, which will be O(n).

But if you need an index to pass it around to other things, you could use a pointer. That is, use a set for faster look-up, and pass pointers (not index's) to specific elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but if you want speed, you'll need to sacrifice space.  Store it in a collection (like an STL set) with the identifier/context as key, and simultaneously store it in a vector.  Of course, you don't want two copies of the data itself, so store it in the set using a smart pointer (auto_ptr or variant) and store it in the vector using a dumb pointer.

Comment: STL containers cannot accept auto_ptrs because they have incompatible ownership semantics.

Comment: I suspected that, which is why I said "or variant".  Would a shared_ptr work?

Comment: Answered my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956764/collection-specialized-for-sharedptr